# Need start button to activate when the timer finishes. Don't want it enabled all the time

Tags: java, android, timer

This is the code I'm using for my countdown timer on java. What I want to do is instead of using `startbtn.setEnabled(true);` I want to enable start button only when the countdown finishes. What should I add or change?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    period = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.period_number);
    startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    cancelbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
    togbtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togBtn);

    cancelbtn.setEnabled(false);
    togbtn.setEnabled(false);

    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            foulCounterA = 0;
            foulCounterB = 0;
            displayForTeamAFoul(foulCounterA);
            displayForTeamBFoul(foulCounterB);

            if (periodCount < 3)
                periodCount = periodCount + 1;
            else periodCount = 4;
            period.setText("Period " + periodCount);

            startbtn.setEnabled(true);
            cancelbtn.setEnabled(true);
            togbtn.setEnabled(true);

            isPaused = false;
            isCanceled = false;

            long millisInFuture = 20000; /////20sec
            long countDownInterval = 1000; /////1sec
            new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    if (isPaused || isCanceled) {
                        cancel();
                    } else {
                        tv1.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        remainingTime = millisUntilFinished;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    if (periodCount < 4)
                        tv1.setText("Times up!");
                    else tv1.setText("Game Over!");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

    togbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (togbtn.isChecked()) {
                isPaused = true;
            } else {
                isPaused = false;
                long millisInFuture = remainingTime;
                long countDownInterval = 1000; /////1sec
                new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        if (isPaused || isCanceled) {
                            cancel();
                        } else {
                            tv1.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                            remainingTime = millisUntilFinished;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                        if (periodCount < 4)
                            tv1.setText("Times up!");
                        else tv1.setText("Game Over!");

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
    });

    cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isCanceled = true;
            period.setText("Period");
            tv1.setText("Timer");
            startbtn.setEnabled(true);
            togbtn.setEnabled(false);
            cancelbtn.setEnabled(false);

            foulCounterA = 0;
            foulCounterB = 0;
            periodCount = 0;
            displayForTeamAFoul(foulCounterA);
            displayForTeamBFoul(foulCounterB);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the code I'm using for my countdown timer on java. What I want to do is instead of using `startbtn.setEnabled(true);` I want to enable start button only when the countdown finishes. What should I add or change?

Comment: Why don't you enable the button in your onFinish() method?

Comment: Add btn.setClickable as well as btn.setEnabled

Comment: @jorjSB Right ty, I couldn't think about that, pretty new to the programming :)

Comment: @MichaelStoddart will look into that aswell for future coding ty.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this solution works, I can write my answer below, to be marked as correct.

Comment: It worked indeed ty. Pretty new to stackoverflow aswell. Is there anything I can do aswell?